# Taking information from one table and query data from two other tables

Tags: php, database

Basically what I want to do is take a table which holds information for two other tables on the database.

```
tbl_server_player contains - StatsID, ServerID, PlayerID
```

Of course in this table it doesn't contain matching ID's. So is it possible to take table 
tbl_playerdata, tbl_playerstats and combine the two tables when calling for the data from tbl_server_player as reference.

For example

```
tbl_server_player
StatsID = 1
ServerID = 5
PlayerID = 10

tbl_playerstats
StatsID = 1
Score = 28921
Kill= 199

tbl_playerdata
PlayerID = 10
SoldierName = Player
GlobalRank = 9
```

So when querying playerstats and playerdata it only selects information needed from tbl_server_player and combines the information. How it is displayed doesn't matter as I would only be wanting to call certain columns.

I am simply unsure of how to set out the

```
$result = mysql_query("select ");.
```

If anyone has an answer for my madness, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a simple `JOIN` query -> `SELECT * FROM tbl_server_player tsp LEFT JOIN tbl_playerstats tps ON tsp.StatsID = tps.StatsID LEFT JOIN tbl_playerdata tpd ON tsp.PlayerID = tpd.PlayerID`

Comment: Wonderful Sean, that worked perfectly.